# How can I reshape an np array into 224,224,3?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

i am working with a big array of images to train a neural network. I have used my own model and now i want to compare the results with mobilenetv2. As far as i know, its neccesary to have an input of (224,224,3) in order to use it.
With the previous model, i reshaped my np arrays into (-1,128,128,3) and it worked, but not for mobilenetv2.
Now, if i try to use mobilenetv2 with my array of 128s, i get this error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "keras_layer" (type KerasLayer).

in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py", line 237, in call  *
        result = smart_cond.smart_cond(training,

    ValueError: Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), dtype=float32)
        * False
        * False
        * 0.99
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
     Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
    
    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        * True
        * False
        * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
      Keyword arguments: {}
```

I suppose is beacause the input isnt 224. But if i try to reshape into that using this, i get this error:

```
X = np.array(X)
print(X.shape)

Y = to_categorical(Y, 2)
X = X.reshape(-1, 224,224,3)




ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 462913536 into shape (224,224)
```

So i am a little bit stuck here, i just want to try the net.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
OK, so i have done as the comment recommend me and resize the images, then getting them into the array and then reshaping the array. This is the code:

```
def get_image(path):
  return np.array(generate_ela(path, 90).resize((224,224))).flatten()/255

---------------------

X = []
Y = []

path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/neural/Au'
for dir, paths, files in os.walk(path):
  for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith('jpg') or filename.endswith('png'):
      full_path = os.path.join(dir, filename)
      X.append(get_image(full_path))
      Y.append(1)
print(len(X), len(Y))

path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/neural/Sp'
for dir, paths, files in os.walk(path):
  for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith('jpg') or filename.endswith('png'):
      full_path = os.path.join(dir, filename)
      X.append(get_image(full_path))
      Y.append(0)
----------------------
X = np.array(X)
print(X.shape)

Y = to_categorical(Y, 2)
X = X.reshape(-1, 224,224,3)

print(X.shape)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=20)
```

But now, when i try to start the training phase, i get this error:

```
epochs = 50
historial = modelo.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = epochs, validation_data = (X_test, Y_test))


    ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 3) are incompatible
```

Comment: Be careful with reshape. You should resize the images. Look into tensorflow’s image resizing functions. And visualize your data! If you look at your data after reshaping, I bet the images will look corrupted.

Comment: The images are OK after reshaping them, and with the first model, all works fine and i get pretty good accuracy classifying them. Are you recommending me to resize every image and then add it to the np array?

Comment: What is the original shape of images, when read from dataset?

Comment: Yes I’m recommending resizing the images and make a new array of those images.

Comment: Hi @javierromero, please ensure that the last Dense Layer(output) has same number of classes as the number of target classes in the training dataset. Also, make sure that you are using `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function as it works with one-hot encoded labels. Thank you!